# How to not close whole JVM when closing xchart chart

Tags: java, charts

I create a chart like this using the xchart java library (http://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/)

```
public void createHistogram(String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, ArrayList<String> xDataSet, ArrayList<Integer> yDataSet) {
    CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder().width(800).height(600).title(title).xAxisTitle(xTitle).yAxisTitle(yTitle).build();

    chart.getStyler().setLegendPosition(LegendPosition.InsideNW);
    chart.getStyler().setHasAnnotations(true);

    chart.addSeries("test1", xDataSet, yDataSet);

    new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

However every time I press exit on the graph's window, it closes down the whole application. Is there a workaround?

Ps. I tried changing "JFrame" to WindowsConstants, ApplicationFrame, and SwingWrapper to see if it has any effect on it but no luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried ‛JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE‛?

Comment: Yeah. Same result. Also tried "HIDE_ON_CLOSE" and "DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE" both just on their own in the brackets, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out an answer. Create a separate class, with an empty form, like so:

```
public GraphsInterface() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 850, 650);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
```

Add a subroutine into this class

```
public void createChart(CategoryChart chart) {
    JPanel panelChart = new XChartPanel(chart);
    contentPane.add(panelChart);
    contentPane.validate();
}
```

Then from where you are creating the graph, just create the object and project it onto the contentPane

```
public void createHistogram(String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, ArrayList<String> xDataSet, ArrayList<Integer> yDataSet) {
    CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder().width(800).height(600).title(title).xAxisTitle(xTitle).yAxisTitle(yTitle).build();

    chart.getStyler().setLegendPosition(LegendPosition.InsideNW);
    chart.getStyler().setHasAnnotations(true);

    chart.addSeries("test1", xDataSet, yDataSet);

    GraphsInterface graph = new GraphsInterface();
    graph.setVisible(true);
    graph.createChart(chart);

}
```